# How to stop timer discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i have this script that sets the timer, but i just don't know how to stop it with a command

```
jb=[]
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def timer(con,time=10):
    timer = time
    ct = con.message.channel.id
    msg = await client.send_message(con.message.channel, time)
    jb.append(con.message.channel.id)
    for i in range(time):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        timer -= 1
        await client.edit_message(msg, new_content=timer)
    num = jb.index(ct)
    del jb[num]
    await client.say("Timer complete")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `asyncio.sleep`, you can use [`client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message).  If the person your bot is communicating with sends a message over that period, you can `break` out of the loop and continue interacting

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def timer(ctx, time: int=10):
    msg = await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, time)
    for newtime in range(time-1, 0, -1):
        resp = await client.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, content="stop", timeout=1)
        if resp:  # They sent a message
            break
        else:
            await client.edit_message(msg, new_content=newtime)
    else:
        # This block is executed if the timer counted all the way down without interruption
```

If you want more complicated acceptance criteria , you can write a `Message -> bool` function and pass it as the `check` argument to `wait_for_message`